# Managing manually installed Monitoring agent for Mongodb Ops manager

Tags: mongodb, administration

I have setup a 3 node replica set of Mongodb servers through Ops Manager. I am seeing the below message as a warning after the setup is done.[Ops Manager server view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLZIJ.png)

"The Monitoring and/or Backup agent(s) for this group are not managed by the Automation Agent. Any manually installed Monitoring and Backup Agents should be stopped and managed Agent(s) added on the Servers View."

I went to the servers view, i thought everything is looking normal but then i came across a server showing as localhost.

attached the server view image

I am not sure why an entry for localhost is also showing up, i did not see localhost in other deployments/groups of Ops Manager.

Now the warning message made sense to me. it is asking to uninstall any manually installed agents, i did searched all the nodes to find if the agents are installed two times but i did not found any.

I used the below command to the installations of Agents

```
rpm -qa | grep -i mongodb-mms-monitoring-agent
rpm -qa | grep -i mongodb-mms-backup-agent
rpm -qa | grep -i mongodb-mms-automation-agent
```

Can someone help me in how to remove the localhost from servers view in Ops manager.

Answer (score 0):

My Issue was resolved after installing the monitoring agent on one of the three servers, doing so uninstalled the monitoring agent from the localhost listing.

All the warnings are gone now.